# EiffelStudio: no autocomplete for local entities

Tags: autocomplete, ide, eiffel

I have tried to use EiffelStudio for a small Eiffel project and I have realized that its autocompletion feature (press the **.** and then a feature list will appear) does not work **for local entities the type of which come from the Eiffel library.**

For example:

- a local *set : ARRAYED_SET[STRING]* wont be autocompleted when writing "*set.*".
- when using the construct ***if attached*** item(some_key) **as** localitems, "*localitems.*" won't be autocompleted

I use Eiffel Studio 14.05 (x86/64) on Linux Mint. I downloaded ES from the official site. How can I tweak the software to autocomplete local entities, too?

Comment: Eiffel itself has very few questions here since it's a rather niche programming language and I honestly don't think you'll get an answer very fast. If I may suggest EiffelStudio has an IRC channel and there usually are a few people there (sometimes just one). I think you'll have a better chance of solving your issue by checking there - but when you do: please post the answer you've gotten here so it could help people with this problem in the future.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, [Eiffel Software user mailing list](http://groups.eiffel.com/) can indeed be used to post _EiffelStudio_-specific questions and requests for help that are not of interest to a wider audience. There are from several tens to one-two hundred posts per month, mostly driven by Eiffel community with expertise posts from Eiffel Software developers when no solution is provided by other participants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried auto-completion with *EiffelStudio 14.05* and it works for both local entities and object test locals (I used a precompiled library in a project created from scratch). It definitely does not work if a project or a particular class was not compiled. If this is not the case, it makes sense either to provide some more details about the situation that causes the issue or to submit a bug report at their [support site](http://support.eiffel.com/) with the description.

**EDIT:** The issue seems to be present in *EiffelStudio 14.05* when editing generic classes.

Comment: You may be right: I think I use "non-precompiled" libraries. I ran precompilation wizard and got a "new base" named base_pre but I think my project uses the simple base (non-precompiled). How can I switch to the precompiled one?

Comment: @user1724641, I've rechecked without a precompiled library and the auto-completion still works. However, as I mentioned, it did not work before the project was compiled. And it was not compiled, because there were some errors in my test class. In other words, if your project has never been (successfully) compiled, auto-completion will not work. You may also try to recompile the project from scratch: exit _EiffelStudio_, start it again, and, after selecting a project, make sure to enable a check-box **Clear** next to an action (it will be **Compile** then).

Comment: My project compiles and works but without the mentioned autocompletion for locals (it works for features). I did what you said but checking **Clear** causes the project not to open. But I think it cleans up the project because next time I tried to open the project a full compilation was done. After this the autocompletion issue was still observable.

Comment: Sorry I ve made a big mistake - I did not mention a "speciality" of my code. I use generic parameters. In this situation autocompletion may not be possible (but I do not see the real cause of this). Some specific code:
`add_node(node : T)
 local
  set : ARRAYED_SET[T]
 do
  create set.make(0)
  set.compare_objects
  put (set, node)
 end`

Comment: @user1724641, indeed auto-completion does not work in a generic class with this feature. Would you submit a bug report to their support site?